# Syntax error when using __init__

Tags: python

I apologize if the answer is obvious, but for some reason, the following code gives me a syntax error at every line after def _ _ init _ _ block.
If I simply comment out init, the entire program works fine however.

```
import graphics
from graphics import *


class Block:

    def __init__(self,x,y,win,fid,length,orien,colour):

        wind = win
        if (orien == "horizontal"):

            topL,dump = getPoint(fid)

            lightRect = Rectangle(getPoint(fid)


  #      else:
   #         x =5



    def draw(self):
        return        


    def undraw(self):
        return


    def highlight(self):
        return


    def unhighlight(self):
        return


    def switchHighlight(self):
        return

    def move(self,target):
        return
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `class Block:` should be `class Block():` and keep track of indentation. it needs to be 4 spaces consistently.and of course, as mchfrnc mentions, the syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

Missing ")" in:

```
lightRect = Rectangle(getPoint(fid)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it may of been too obvious... DX